# Internal working of greater than/ less than

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I was just wondering how is the result of greater than / less than computed and returned to the high level languages.

I'm looking for the hardware gate model here.

Lets use a uniform example to explain, say 5 > 3.

Comment: @Downvoter: I personally don't like this question either. It is not in my taste. But that does not give me the moral right to downvote it because it is clearly formulated, is a programming question, is not a duplicate, etc... Let's refrain from downvoting questions which we personally dislike.

Comment: There's an ALU that does this on every uP/CPU. We just pass literals/references to it, and it will set a number of flags to whether the operands are equal, equal to zero, greater or lesser.

Comment: Are you saying you want someone to explain the electrical engineering and hardware circuitry that supports those machine code instructions, then explain how the hardware does its fetch/execute of the instruction and applies it, and how the high level language compiler compiles into machine code? Basically everything from the low level electrical engineering to the high level code and everything between, linking them together?

Comment: @Armen: If I understand it correctly, it's not entirely a programming question, but is still very closely related. It sounds like it's half systems programming theory and half electrical engineering. Still, if I understand it correctly, the poster is asking for a lot, something not suited to a simple answer here. (EDIT: not saying that I was the downvoter though, as I wasn't)

Comment: I did the downvote because author is not seeking an answer (which is at plain sight on any CS/digital logic book), he is  merely trying to get reputation. I don't up/down vote on polls (or that one about eng. jokes), and those are pretty useless, programming-wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is usually implemented via subtraction with carry-detection.

From a gating perspective, subtracting binary numbers is performed by passing matched pairs of bits from each operand through a subtractor:

```
            +-----+
carry_in -->|     |
            |     |--> a_minus_b
       a -->| SUB |
            |     |--> carry_out
       b -->|     |
            +-----+

a_minus_b = carry_in ⊕ a ⊕ b
carry_out = (carry_in ∧ b) ∨ (¬a ∧ (carry_in ∨ b))
```

Bit 0 from arguments `a` and `b` is passed through the first subtractor, with a carry_in of 0. Bit 1 from each argument is passed through the second subtractor, with carry_in set to the carry_out of the bit-0 stage. This continues down the chain until the final carry_out at the end sets the CPU's carry flag, which holds a 1 if a < b, otherwise 0.

Additionally, every a_minus_b is ORed together and negated, with the result going into the CPU's zero flag, denoting that a = b.

These flags can be tested by machine instructions, which are generated by compilers when you write `if (a < b) { ... }`.

I'll leave 5 > 3 as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This works for unsigned values. For signed values, you need overflow detection too.

Comment: In the context of subtraction, "borrow" is often used instead of "carry".

Comment: For signed values, it's `carry_out ⊕ sign` that's used to test for `a < b`).